# Remove White Background While Canvas Is Being Drawn or Redrawn

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I use the code below to draw part of the image. Every time I change the image. The widget turns white for a few milliseconds. Any idea how to make the widget transparent while the canvas is being drawn?

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
PartImagePainter(
      originalImageWidth: imageWidth, originalImageHeight: imageHeight,
      imageData: imageData,
      rect: imageRects[index]
  )
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class PartImagePainter extends StatefulWidget {
  Uint8List imageData;
  int originalImageWidth;
  int originalImageHeight;
  Rect rect;

  PartImagePainter({required this.imageData, required this.originalImageWidth, required this.originalImageHeight, required this.rect});

  @override
  _PartImagePainterState createState() => _PartImagePainterState();
}

class _PartImagePainterState extends State<PartImagePainter> {
  Future<ui.Image> getImage(Uint8List imageData) async {
    final codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(
      imageData,
      targetWidth: widget.originalImageWidth,
      targetHeight: widget.originalImageHeight,
    );

    final image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
    return image;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getImage(widget.imageData),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            return paintImage(snapshot.data);
          } else {
            // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            return SizedBox(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        });
  }

  paintImage(image) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: ImagePainter(image, widget.rect),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: widget.rect.height,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  ui.Image resImage;

  Rect rectCrop;

  ImagePainter(this.resImage, this.rectCrop);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (resImage == null) {
      return;
    }
    final Rect rect = Offset.zero & size;
    final Size imageSize =
    Size(resImage.width.toDouble(), resImage.height.toDouble());
    FittedSizes sizes = applyBoxFit(BoxFit.fitWidth, imageSize, size);

    Rect inputSubRect = rectCrop;
    final Rect outputSubRect =
    Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.destination, rect);

    canvas.drawImageRect(resImage, inputSubRect, outputSubRect, Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use a Stack with a Positioned.fill to make the background transparent. Example:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ),
    PartImagePainter(
      originalImageWidth: imageWidth,
      originalImageHeight: imageHeight,
      imageData: imageData,
      rect: imageRects[index],
    ),
  ],
)
```

You can also use a Container with a transparent color. Example:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: PartImagePainter(
    originalImageWidth: imageWidth,
    originalImageHeight: imageHeight,
    imageData: imageData,
    rect: imageRects[index],
  ),
),
```